# Transfer of variables between app and extension swift

Tags: xcode, swift, ios9

I'm creating a project in swift in which a variable that the user can set a value to is located in the main view controller. I want this variable to be received and be usable in an extension (e.g. Photo editing extension, Today extension, Audio unit extension, etc.). I've seen transfers of variables between different view controllers, just never between completely different folders (the main folder and the extension folder). How do you do this (and in way that a beginner could understand + execute)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make singleton class which have getter method for those variable, you can access from where ever you want to access on them through out the app ! here is some useful resource for singleton class :-  https://thatthinginswift.com/singletons/